# UI elements does not update when they should

Tags: android, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

I have a download service which updates the UI trough callbacks. For an example if I cancel a downloading task, than the UI at the correct item should change accordingly. 
The UI update method looks like this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            downloadSwitch.setClickable(true);
            downloadSwitch.setChecked(false);
            downloadSwitchText.setText(R.string.switch_download_available);
            downloadSwitchText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            downloadSwitch.setDownloadState(State.READY);
        }
    });
```

I have noticed, that sometimes after calling this method, only the text changes, but the switch stays checked or vice versa. Have someone run in to this issue ?

EDIT_1: I think I should mention that items are different fragments in a `ViewPager` in the `Activity` and these methods are located in the fragment

EDIT_2: Custom Switch

```
public class DownloadSwitch extends Switch {
private static final String TAG = DownloadSwitch.class.getSimpleName();

private State downloadState;

public DownloadSwitch(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DownloadSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initCostumeAttrs(attrs);
}

public DownloadSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initCostumeAttrs(attrs);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public DownloadSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initCostumeAttrs(attrs);
}

private void initCostumeAttrs(AttributeSet attributeSet){
    TypedArray attributes = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.DownloadSwitch, 0, 0);
    int intState = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.DownloadSwitch_state, 0);

    switch (intState){
        case 0:
            downloadState = State.READY;
            setChecked(false);
            break;
        case 1:
            downloadState = State.DOWNLOADING;
            setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            downloadState = State.DONE;
            setChecked(true);
            break;
    }
    attributes.recycle();
}

@Override
public void setClickable(boolean clickable) {
    super.setClickable(clickable);
    if(clickable){
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    } else {
        setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    super.setChecked(checked);
    changeColor(checked);
}

private void changeColor(boolean checked) {
    int thumbColor;
    int trackColor;
    if(checked){
        thumbColor = Color.argb(225, 226, 6, 19);
        trackColor = Color.argb(225, 0, 244, 217);
    } else {
        thumbColor = Color.argb(225, 255, 255, 255);
        trackColor = Color.argb(225, 221, 221, 221);
    }

    try {
        getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(thumbColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(trackColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use to notice there is sometimes `NullPointerException` at the `changeColor()`. Maybe it is related to that? When I load the activity all the UI elements are set correctly. This occurs only if I do real time changes.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using CheckBox ?

Comment: I am using a custom view which extends Switch

Comment: @parohy can you show code of custom view? You are doing something wrong there. Probably on `downloadSwitch.setDownloadState(State.READY);`

Comment: Code look fine for me. Check whether  downloadSwitch.setChecked(false) working fine in custom view

Comment: remove the line downloadSwitch.setChecked(false)  and run. it already set false while change the downloading state

Comment: It did not help. I still run into this.